# Custom Cocoapod always returns "No such module XXX"

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I followed the guide found [here](https://samwize.com/2017/10/01/creating-a-swift-framework-cocoapods/)

This is my `.podspec` file

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name         = "iOSUtils"
  s.version      = "0.0.1"
  s.summary      = "A really short description of MyFramework."
  s.description  = <<-DESC
  A much much much longer description of MyFramework.
                   DESC
  s.homepage     = "https://github.com/xxxxxxx/ios-utils"
  s.license      = "MIT"
  s.author       = { "xxxxxxx" => "xxxxxxx@xxxxxxx.io" }
  s.source       = { :path => '.' }
  # s.source       = { :git => "https://github/samwize/MyFramework", :tag => "#{s.version}" }
  s.source_files  = "Source/**/*.swift"
end
```

My solution is laid out as
[image]

And for testing purposes I created a simple service

```
public class TestService {
    static public let shared = TestService()
    private init() { }

    public func foo() {
        print("bar")
    }
}
```

The `Podfile` of my project that will use this new framework looks like `pod 'iOSUtils', :path => '../iOSUtils'` and running install returns success messages.

When I then try and import my module however, I get the `no such module` error and cannot build.

Looking at my project also, I cannot see the source included under development pods

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding your package name into the `s.source_files` of your `iOSUtils.podspec` file.

```
  s.source_files  = "iOSUtils/Source/**/*.swift"
```